# Keeping floated divs inside page constraints

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this can be done without javascript, but I hope it has a solution.
Consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PPeYH/

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
    border: 1px solid;
    min-height: 3em;
}
.container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
#placeholder-body {
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
}
.split-tile {
    float: left;
}
.split-left {
    width: 60%;
}
.split-left .content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    max-width: 360px;
}
.split-right {
    width: 40%;
}
.split-right .content {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 240px;
}
```

---

```
<div><div class="content container">Header</div></div>
<div id="placeholder-body">
    <div><div class="content container">Some content</div></div>

    <div class="tile-1 split-tile split-left">
        <div class="content">60% width.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile-2 split-tile split-right">
        <div class="content">40%</div>
    </div>

    <div><div class="content container">Some content</div></div>
</div>
<div><div class="content container">Footer</div></div>
```

The structure you see here, is a simplified version of a RWD structure. We need the entire layout to stay inside it's boundaries. If you change the browser width up or down, you will see that the divs marked "60%" and "40%" do not respect the boundaries of the rest of the divs.

"Why don't you just wrap the 60% and 40% divs in a container?", you might ask. 
Well, the DOM structure presented here is laid out using a CMS in an already complex system. It would require more than just a little refactoring to change this. I will have to live with the tiles being laid out the way they are.

So my question is this; is there a way to achieve a 60/40 split on the middle divs in such a way that they will keep to the left and right edges of the rest of the layout, using ONLY css?

**UPDATE:**
I cannot constrain the #placeholder-body to a max-width either, because my designer wants me to make full-width background colors to some of the divs in the structure.

Comment: I reckon it needs a container... Its just if you have the widths set to any % other than 50:50, the split between the two boxes is always going to shift towards the smaller side as the page grows larger. - except if you can do Lolo's solution and just limit the width of everything to 600

Comment: Yes I know. :( But unfortunately I cannot create a container for the divs unless I create some JS solution to it. Which I hoped to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can modify `#placeholder-body` style, then solution is simple:

```
#placeholder-body {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/PPeYH/1/

Another possibility:

```
.split-tile {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}
.split-left .content {
    width: 60%;
}
.split-right .content {
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 40%;
}
.split-left {
    height: 0;
}
```

Here no float is used, but left title has height set to 0, but overflow is visible, so it looks fine. The problem is when it's content is longer than in right title. You can also set negative top margin on `split-right` instead of setting height to 0 on `split-left`, but you must know exact height.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/PPeYH/3/

Beside that It is possible media query and `calc` from CSS3:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 638px) {
    .split-left {
        width: 360px;
        margin-left: calc(50% - 300px);
    }
    .split-left .content {
        width: 360px;
    }
    .split-right {
        width: 240px;
        margin-right: calc(50% - 300px);
    }
    .split-right .content {
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 240px;
    }   
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/PPeYH/5/

Comment: Yes, that would be a good solution. But unfortunately my designer wants me to also provide full width grey background for some of the content, making it impossible for me to constrain the #placeholder-body either. This was unclear in the question. I will update it.

Comment: I've added 2 more solutions, you may take a look.

Comment: I thank you for your contribution. Solution #1 does not apply as explained above. Solution #2 is good, but not something we can use because split-left will always have a greater height than split-right. Solution #3 is probably the best, but why does background color set in content above and below continue inside the split-tiles?  http://jsfiddle.net/gc2aK/

Comment: If you add `clear: both` then it looks normal: http://jsfiddle.net/gc2aK/2/. BTW if you can reverse order of split-left/split-right, it is possible to adapt solution #2: http://jsfiddle.net/74sm6/

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. :) I will go for solution #3 as this looks like the most robust solution.

Answer (score -1):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G76M2/)
if you insert the split-tiles inside another container it works.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tile-1 split-tile split-left">
        <div class="content">
            60% width.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile-2 split-tile split-right">
        <div class="content">
            40%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```